# XPrivacy showing Kiwi Browser calling `shell/start` and `shell/exec`, what is this?

Tags: shell, xprivacy, kiwi-browser

According to the XPrivacy app, shortly after starting the Kiwi Browser app, the app executes the following:

[image]

It's a shell command with `/system/bin/cmd package compile -r shared com.kiwibrowser.browser`

It's very weird in my opinion because I **have never seen something like this behavior in any app before**. Executing a shell command is weird and unusual and this compiling command too.

My guess: It seems like it has an embedded app in itself that it tries to compile and run? Maybe even malware? I could be wrong. What is it doing? Does anybody know?

I'm not a programmer and don't know too much, that's why I need your thoughts.